# How to provide a 64-bit thread identifier for _beginthreadex

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, 64-bit, crt

I'm trying to port some code to 64-bit, but it seems that the thread <strike>address</strike> identifier in `_beginthreadex` is `unsigned int` which is 32-bits and I can't pass/receive a 64-bit <strike>address</strike> identifier from the function:

```
uintptr_t _beginthreadex( // NATIVE CODE
   void *security,
   unsigned stack_size,
   unsigned ( __stdcall *start_address )( void * ),
   void *arglist,
   unsigned initflag,
   unsigned *thrdaddr // <-- 32-bit address
);
```

I checked the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), but I didn't see a 64-bit version of the function. Am I including the wrong header, per-processor flag or is there some other way to create a thread with a 64-bit <strike>address</strike> identifier?

### Update

The documentation states that the `thrdaddr` parameter is 32-bit:

> Thrdaddr
>
> ```
> Points to a 32-bit variable that receives the thread identifier. Might be NULL, in which case it is not used.
> ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `thrdaddr` parameter receives the thread ID. It is not the address of the thread function. It appears to be an exceedingly badly named parameter.

The `start_address` parameter is the thread function pointer and you can pass your 64 bit function pointer in that parameter.

---

Your update to the question suggests that you believe that the thread ID is a 64 bit value on 64 bit Windows. That is a mis-think. Thread IDs are 32 bit values on all flavours of Windows.

Comment: I thought that `thrdaddr` means "thread address", but I guess it means "thread identifier". In any case, the documentation still states that the identifier is a 32-bit value.

Comment: Thread IDs are indeed 32 bit values. The documentation is correct and the parameter is correctly typed. It is just misleadingly named.

Comment: OK, got it... I didn't realize that it's not possible to have a 64-bit value for the Thread ID. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> *Thrdaddr*
>
> Points to a 32-bit variable that receives the thread identifier. Might be NULL, in which case it is not used.

In other words, `thrdaddr` gets the thread id. It is not an address for the thread.

In 64-bit, all pointers are 64-bits. So this just works.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting some of the arguments mixed up.  The address for your thread proc will be passed in as `start_address`.  `thrdaddr` is an optional parameter than receives the thread ID.

```
HANDLE hThread;
unsigned threadID;

hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(
    NULL,
    0,
    &YourThreadProc, // this is your thread procedure
    NULL,
    0,
    &threadID); // threadID will hold the ID of the new thread
```

Comment: I was (miss)reading `thrdaddr` as "thread address", however, I'm aware that it's not the thread address but the identifier.

Comment: It is a very poor name.  The function will work in 64-bit code just fine, though.