# What does Get­Window­Thread­Process­Id return?

Tags: winapi

```cpp
DWORD GetWindowThreadProcessId(
  HWND    hWnd,
  LPDWORD lpdwProcessId
);
```

According to the docs, the return value is the identifier of the thread that created the window. What does that mean?

I guess I'm just wondering what a threadID has got to do with the processID, what is it and what is it there for - does it validate the processID in some way? I want to just discard it because the processID is what I'm after.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198218/how-to-provide-a-64-bit-thread-identifier-for-beginthreadex thread identifiers are 32-bit, not 64-bit. Do you think 2 billion thread ids is not enough?

Comment: @CodeCaster Thanks, yeah actually that was a bit of a stupid question I can see in the declaration it's a DWORD not a pointer type. No I just don't know why a function asking for a processID returns a threadID in the first place, what does it mean in the context of this function?

Comment: [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowthreadprocessid) looks clear enough: `Retrieves the identifier of the thread that created the specified window and, optionally, the identifier of the process that created the window.`

Comment: Oddly enough, the API is not documented whether or how it returns an error. [Thread Handles and Identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/thread-handles-and-identifiers) explains what thread identifiers are.

Comment: The function returns both the threadID and process ID. The name is "get window thread and process ID". Not sure why you think it is asking only for the process ID.

Comment: Windows are owned by the thread that created them. Threads are owned by processes. So each window has an associated owning thread and process. This function simply takes a window as input and returns both the owning thread and process. You can do whatever you like with the values returned, including discarding one or more of them.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I see, thanks. And is there a situation where an error occurs and one or both is invalid? Can threadID being invalid tell me processID is invalid for example?

Comment: or both valid or both invalid, if tid == 0

Comment: A valid window is owned by a thread which in turn is owned by a process. If the window handle is not valid then obviously you won't get either thread or process ID.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Getting the literal question out of the way up front, [GetWindowThreadProcessId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowthreadprocessid)

> [r]etrieves the identifier of the thread that created the specified window and, optionally, the identifier of the process that created the window.

That's fairly self-explanatory, so long as you understand the underlying relationships:

- Windows are owned by threads. When a thread creates a window, both enter an inseparable relationship, that lasts until the window is destroyed.
- Threads are owned by processes. Once a thread is created in a particular process, it belongs to that process until it terminates.

In other words: Every window is owned by a single thread, which in turn belongs to a single process. That relationship is fixed for the lifetime of a window.

---

With the documentation talking about *"the identifier"* it sounds as if that were unambiguous. That is not the case as the system provides two distinct ways to identify a thread (or process): By ID and by handle.

IDs (as returned by this API) are simply numeric values, such as the value `42`. They can be freely passed around, returned by and provided to command line tools, and so on. They come with no strings attached. A corollary of this is, that the meaning of a particular value changes over time.

Handles, on the other hand, are tied to the actual object. As long as a client holds a handle, the system will keep the referenced object alive. Consequently, the referenced object doesn't change, allowing clients to make assumptions about lifetimes.